# Can a wizard or a witch use two wands at the same time?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

Wizards and witches can lose their wands in duels, or other situations. Can the new owner use two or more wands at the same time to cast stronger spells?

Comment: A better question is, is it better to use 2 wands in _parallel_ or in _series_?

Comment: @Gallifreyan - depends if you're part of the Resistance

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To . . . or capacitance! _ba-doom-tshhh_

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Yes, it seems**

Harry does it in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*. (Emphasis mine)

> As Ron ran to pull Hermione out of the wreckage, Harry took his
>   chance: He leapt over an armchair and wrested the three wands from
>   Draco’s grip, pointed all of them at Greyback, and yelled, “Stupefy!”
>   The werewolf was lifted off his feet by the **triple spell**, flew up to the
>   ceiling, and then smashed to the ground.
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 23</sup>

Him using three wands apparently did make the spell stronger, and later we find out that probably all had changed their allegiance to Harry when he snatched them from Draco.

But it doesn't seem to be commonly used, there don't seem to be other examples. Maybe it is inconvenient to perform the correct movements and the advantage it provides isn't that great.

Comment: maybe using 3 wands would use 3 times the 'magical energy' and exhaust people quicker?

Comment: "Him using three wands apparently did make the spell stronger" -- I don't see any strong evidence of that in the quote.

Comment: @Yakk It isn't very strong, but 'triple spell' has been explicitly used, and the relatively extreme effect it caused has been described in detail, so it does suggest that that is the case.